# Need help to grab only most recent entry of a specific instance from a troubleshooting log

Tags: powershell, api, foreach

I wrote a PowerShell script which uses APIs to parse through non-compliant (NC) mobile device logs from our MDM to determine if a device has been NC for over 60 days and delete it. We realized that current compliant devices that become NC might have an older record from a previous time they were NC. We only want to grab the latest log entry.  Any help to understand how to only grab the most recent NC entry would be great.

Have not been able to write code that would only grab the latest non-compliant entry from the logs. Currently it will grab all NC log entries ≥ 60 days from each device that is NC.  In the function I return the serial number of the device if it has been NC for over 60 days.
The code below is the function that I wrote to parse the event logs and does work, minus the fact that it grabs any older NC log entry ≥60 days. I'm assuming I could put some code in the foreach statement.

```
function get_events {
    Param([string]$serial)

    $sixtydays = (Get-Date).AddDays(-60)

    $url = "https://$ourmdm/api/mdm/devices/eventlog?searchby=serialnumber&id=$serial&pagesize=10000&dayrange=365"

    $headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
    $headers.Add("tenant-code", $Code)
    $headers.Add("Authorization", $Auth)

    try {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers $headers
    } catch {
        $null = "Device Info Not Found"
    }

    $ServicePoint = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::FindServicePoint($url)
    $ServicePoint.CloseConnectionGroup("") | Out-Null

    $data = $response.DeviceEventLogSearchResult.DeviceEventLogEntries
    foreach ($event in $data) {
        if ($event.Event -eq 'ComplianceStatusChanged') {
            if ($event.EventDataList.NewValue -eq 'NonCompliant') {
                $request = $event.Timestamp
                $eventdate = [DateTime]$request
                if ($eventdate -lt $sixtydays) {
                    return $serial
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `get_events -serial 'something' | Select-Object -Last 1`; of course, you could consider returning an object `return @{ serial = $serial; date = $eventdate }` instead of `return $serial` and then `get_events -serial 'something' | sort-object -Property date | Select-Object -Last 1` ( or `Select-Object -First 1`?)